# Is it possible to use SWC files with Flash CS3 Professional?

Tags: facebook, flash, swc, cs3

I hate CS5, so I'm trying to stick with CS3.  However, I'm doing a Facebook app, and I need to use the GraphAPI, which is a swc file.  So far, I cannot figure out how to use the swc file with Flash CS3 Professional.  CS5 has a "browse to swc file" option in "Publish Settings".  CS3 does not - only "browse to folder".  Is this even possible in CS3, or is my only option to switch over to CS5?  (Again, I'm talking about Flash Professional, not Flash Builder.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember CS3 can use SWC, but only for UI components. You had to place the SWC in the config/components folder and then access them through the components panel. (Probably with a reloading of the panel/rebooting the IDE for good measure).

You can add the SWC to the fla classpath (*file> publish settings> settings*) but for class libraries I *think* you will get runtime errors.

Have you had a look at [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) as an alternative to CS5?